# Printing to View during an Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

Silly question: in my code I collect all the messages to be displayed in the view in a buffer. On the code bellow if my Try{ } fails and go straight to Catch{ } the error will be buffered but the controller wont have the chance to assign to the view, right? How would you guys solve this kind of situation?

```
MyController
{
//...

try {
  // ... do something

  $this->_messages[] = array('success', 'Thank You.');
}    
catch (Exception $e) {
  $this->_messages[] = array('error', 'Oops! There was an error.');
}

/**
 * flush all buffered messages to the view
 */
$flashmsg = $this->_flashMessenger->getMessages();
if (!empty($flashmsg)) $this->_messages[] = $flashmsg[0];      
$this->view->messages = $this->_messages;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not like this approach!
In my application if something goes into the catch means that the application is broken, then log the error and redirect to view type "Oops ... Sorry"!
When I print to the Messages view, are always significant to the inherent logic of the application flow, for me to decide the type of message (success or bad) and not a catch!

Comment: Here it happens that the database is busy and a query time out. On this case you generate an exception but there is no need to finish the application but simply to inform the client to try again. Unless I automated the application to try again for 3x before actually finishing in Oops... interesting. Thanks.